How do I display a window with information when hovering over an image?"
The picture appears, but the information box note. It's a code for web and mobile application. I just want to show more information about the image when the user click with the mouse or pass the finger over the image.


        .container {
         position: relative;
         display: inline-block;
        }

        .info-box {
          visibility: hidden;
          width: 200px;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          color: #333;
          text-align: center;
          border-radius: 5px;
          padding: 10px;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 1;
          bottom: 125%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translateX(-50%);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }

        .container:hover .info-box,
        .container img:hover + .info-box {
         visibility: visible;
       }
 
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81YFrKSH40L._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg" alt="Imagem" width="114" height="114">
  <div class="info-box">
    <!-- Informações adicionais -->
    <h2>Título da Informação</h2>
    <p>Descrição da informação.</p>
  </div>
</div>




The basic and easiest way to add a tooltip is you can use the title attribute in the image.


 <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81YFrKSH40L._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg" alt="Imagem" width="114" height="114" title="5 Minute Dungeon">



Or if you want to explore more on others.
Here are some references you can start of:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp
https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

Your hover is working properly. Just was hidden on the left side (out of screen). I commented the left, bottom and transform for you to know where is your .info-box and what transform translate you need to add then  (here I added transform: translateY(-100%);). I also added max-width: fit-content; for the container not to take the whole width (pb when not hovering on image). You can also remove transform and use (bottom: -100%; left: 0%;) for example.


.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: fit-content;
 }

 .info-box {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /* bottom: 125%; */
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* transform: translateX(-50%); */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

 .container:hover .info-box{
  visibility: visible;
}
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81YFrKSH40L._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg" alt="Imagem" width="114" height="114">
  <div class="info-box">
    <!-- Informações adicionais -->
    <h2>Título da Informação</h2>
    <p>Descrição da informação.</p>
  </div>
</div>




Try:
.info-box {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
